# View selection simple search anomaly - is this working properly?

Tags: lotus-notes

I created a help desk database view of outstanding jobs and this needed to be further restricted by excluding those with a numerical status of 20 or 23 so

I created several simple conditions:
[image: simple search]

and this appeared to work fine until I noticed that it was NOT selecting items with a numstatus of 0

Twiddling the dropdown from "Simple Search" to "Formula" switches to the equivalent formula language which is a little unexpected:

[image: formula-1]

but this still appears correct yet still doesn't select numstatus=0 items.

Hacking the formula to

```
SELECT (!@Contains(Status; "Completed")) & ((Form = "Support ticket") | (Form = "Memo")) & (!NumStatus =23) & (!NumStatus =20)
```

fixes the problem.

Is this working as designed or is it a bug/feature?

Answer (score 0):

The auto-generated formula does look a bit strange. It does seem like a bug, but perhaps there's one case where it would *might* make sense to work in your hacked version but not in the auto-generated version.

If the value of numstatus is not an number and instead a string value "0", then perhaps the value fails the greater than and less than comparison tests, but passes the not equals test.

Regardless, your version is more readible and makes perfect sense, so whether there's a bug or not for the auto-generated version, you are doing the right thing.

Comment: Numstatus is set as a "number - editable" field on the "Support ticket" form.  Very odd.